# How to Customize Windows Explorer Toolbar

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

I am trying to customize (add my own menus to the) Windows Explorer toolbar. From web I came to know that it is possible to that by editing the registry. So I changed the owner of

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksItemsSelected\]
```

and set permissions as full control to me. Adding keys to the above registry didn’t work for me in Windows 7 and 8 as well.

I installed the tools “ CustomExplorerToolbar.exe" and “ExplorerToolbarEditor.exe” that worked in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8. Also using that tool I can only add existing menus but not create new one.

So I did the technique as described below, I created a shell in commandstore.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\command1]
```

And called that in,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksItemsSelected\]
@=”command1”
```

The above method worked for me in Windows 7, But it is not working in Windows 8. Is there any method to implement that?

Comment: have you tried the tool OldNewExplorer? Do the customization works now also in Windows 8?

Comment: I have not tried OldNewExplorer because that is removing the ribbon itself. I want to customize the ribbon instead of removing it.

Comment: the ribbon can't be really customized

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 8 Explorer comes with a ribbon. This ribbon can't be customized. You can try to use [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-117/) to disable the ribbon, now the old tweaks should work again.

[image]

Comment: How can I implement a floating window concept ? I have used foldersize. It opens only when I open the windows explorer and gives the each files and folders size. How it works ?